# Connecting Google colab with Mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb, google-colaboratory, mongodb-compass

Can we connect google colab with mongodb compass in local system?

If we can connect the how? It is connecting, but access is not guarantied to my google colab.

---

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-5176aa9cc8ed> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 myclient.list_database_names()

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/topology.py in _select_servers_loop(self, selector, timeout, address)
    267             # No suitable servers.
    268             if timeout == 0 or now > end_time:
--> 269                 raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
    270                     f"{self._error_message(selector)}, Timeout: {timeout}s, Topology Description: {self.description!r}"
    271                 )

ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 64ef16ab2ab44cf8832ed0aa, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
```